# Saving Memory while using large lists

Tags: python

EDIT:

I need help to turn the code below, especially the list, into a generator so that I can save memory on my computer.

I converted doclist into an iterable object, and deleted slist and seuslist, which previously was a large list of names. 
https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/

```
seuslist1 = open('/Users/AJ/Desktop/Dropbox/DOS_Python/docs/US/socialentrepreneurship_US_list.txt', mode= 'r+')
seuslist = seuslist1.read()
slist = seuslist.split('\n') 
slist = slist[:len(slist)-1] #I have to take out the last entry because of a weird space. Also explore using OSwalk later. 

#I switched to just using a list of docs because it's easier to deal with than a dictionary

doclist = []
for i, doc in enumerate(slist):
    string = 'docs/US/', doc
    string = ''.join(string)
    doclist.append(open(string, mode='r+').read())



#clear these variables to free up memory. Turn doclist into an generator object to save memory.
doclist = iter(doclist)   
del seuslist
del slist

seuslist1.close()
```

Comment: Generators save memory by loading the items _one thing at a time_, thereby not requiring the construction of an entire list. If you've already constructed the list, there is no point turning it into a generator.

Comment: that's very helpful. how would i turn what I have into a generator?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to have all of your documents open at the same time and in memory. This definitely where your memory issues are coming from. Can  you just do them one at a time?

Comment: no it's not necessary (though I wonder if that's going to affect my functions down the line where I assume that all the documents are open). How would I grab the docs one at a time?

Comment: Can we now safely edit this question or open a new one pertaining to what you are _actually doing_ so we can help you possibly come up with a better solution? Sounds like there's some significant refactoring that needs to happen (use of generators, memory management, redesigning later things to iterate over the data properly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic problem, as you've noted, is that you're keeping all the contents of all those files in a single enormous list. Luckily, turning that list into a generator is quite simple. To keep things readable and Pythonic, we'll rename `doclist` to simply `docs`, since it's no longer a list.

```
# Use a generator expression to quickly create a generator.
# This will iterate over ever entry in slist.
# For each entry: build the path, open the file, read it, and yield the contents
docs = (open(path).read() for path in ('docs/US/'+entry for entry in slist))

for doc in docs:
    print(len(doc)) # Do something useful here.
```

---

A couple of things to bear in mind when using generators like this.

First, it will help you with your memory problems, because you only ever have one file's contents in memory at once (unless you store it elsewhere, but that's probably a bad idea, because of the aforementioned memory issues).

Second, each file is loaded only when the iteration (`for doc in docs`) progresses to the next step. This means that if your process takes a long time on each iteration (or even if it doesn't), you could modify files while the process is running, for better or for worse.

Third, the generator expression here isn't the most robust thing ever, since you've got those bare `open` calls, any one of which could throw an Exception and kill the remainder of your processing. To make it sturdier, you'd want to write an actual generator function like in [Calpratt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22823875/2069350), so you can use context managers, wrap up Exceptions on a per-file basis, and so on.

Finally, remember that a generator may only be used *once* as-is! Once you exhaust it, it's done. This is usually fine, but you need to make sure you extract all the information you'll need the first time through (besides, you don't want to be re-reading all those files over and over anyway!).

Comment: can you point me to keywords that let me explore how to do operations on generators?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
main_file = '/Users/AJ/Desktop/Dropbox/DOS_Python/docs/US/socialentrepreneurship_US_list.txt'

def data_from_file_generator():
    with open(main_file, mode= 'r+') as path_file:
        for my_path in path_file:
            with open("docs/US/" + my_path, mode='r+') as data_file:
                yield data_file.read()
```